# angular based PWA does not work on Google cloud platform but works on firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, progressive-web-apps

I am new to pwa and google cloud. I am trying to create and host simple pwa on the web. so far I have hosted it on firebase https://pwademo-cba43.firebaseapp.com/  . on firebase PWA is installable and the service work is also detected. but the problem arises when I host it on google cloud. it does not even detect service worker and also does not point to start URL. is there any proper tutorial available to make it work?

tried changing the start URL. created service worker again

Comment: Are you using a secure certificate? PWAs only work over HTTPS

Comment: Have you run the Lighthouse audit tool on the Google cloud URL? That may tell you what you need to fix to make it a valid PWA.